# gtsummary::inline_text cite column header N in stratified table

Tags: text, inline, gtsummary

I was not able to find in documentation and tutorials how to cite the header Ns (see picture below) with `gtsummary::inline_text`. I found a workaround: `tbl_penguins$N` for the overall N in blue and `tbl_penguins$df_by$n[tbl_penguins$df_by$by == "Biscoe"]` for the strata N in red, but I am guessing there is a cleaner way to do the same by using the `inline_text` function.

I would be glad for help :)

Thanks!
Matthieu

[image]

Code used to produce table:

```
library(palmerpenguins)
tab <- tbl_summary(
  penguins,
  include = c(species, bill_length_mm),
  by = island 
) %>%
  add_overall()
```

Comment: I think your solution is a good one. These quantities are available for all variables using `inline_text()` as well. For example, you can report `"N_obs"`  for species to get the Ns you're after.

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg thanks! using ``pattern = "{N_obs}" works perfectly :) However, it is counter intuitive to have to set the level for an overall N, if I don't it returns an NA

Comment: Fair, but it wasn't written to report headers

Comment: No I agree, it was not a criticism :) I hope it was not interpreted that way. maybe an idea? it's just that these functions are so useful for reporting, the more they can do, the more you want to them do to! thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1):

Answer: use `pattern = "{N_obs}"`.

`tbl_penguins$df_by$n[tbl_penguins$df_by$by == "Biscoe"]` is equivalent to `inline_text(tab, column = "Biscoe", variable = "species", level = "Adelie", pattern = "{N_obs}")`.